# Prove $f''(x) \geq c$ for all $x >0$ and some constant $c >0$ is not bounded from above

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, functions

Let $f:(0,\infty) \to \mathbb{R}$ be a function which is twice differentiable and for which $f''(x) \geq c \;\forall x >0$ and some constant $c>0$.

Prove $f$ is not bounded from above.

Here's my try at this problem:

Given $f''(x) \geq c$; $c >0$.

When $f''(x) = c$; $c>0$, $f''(x)$ is positive, hence the curve of $f$ is concave up.

When $f$ is concave up, it is not bounded from above.

Does this make sense?

Comment: No. Because constant functions satisfy the condition

Comment: wait wouldn't constant functions have a f''(x) of 0? not positive?

Comment: Is the inequality what you intended?  As has been pointed out, constant functions obviously satisfy $f''(x)≤c$ for some positive $c$ (indeed, for any positive $c$).  In particular, your inequality does not imply that $f''(x)$ is ever positive.

Comment: Didn't you mean $f''(x)\ge c>0$?

Comment: sorry for the late response but yes I did.

Answer (score 5):

Assuming you meant $f''(x)\ge c>0$:

For $x>1$ we have $f'(x)-f'(1)=(x-1)f''(\xi)\ge (x-1)c$ for some $\xi\in(1,a)$ by the IVT. In particular, $f'(x)\ge c$ for all $x>\frac{f'(1)}c+2=:x_0$. Then $f(x)\ge f(x_0)+c(x-x_0)$ for all $x>x_0$, which makes $f$ unbounded.

Comment: I fixed a typo in the first line: $f''$ for $f'$$.

Comment: I think you meant the MVT.

Comment: i think the second line would be  $x>2-\frac{f'(1)}{c}$